# how can i refer to M-x [command] in .emacs?

Tags: emacs

how can i refer to M-x [command] in .emacs?

I copy-pasted some code which made some of my Evil commands worked, but I don't understand how it is working as of now and can't replicate it.

I imagine it has something to do with require.

Maybe my question should be: *How do I find out what package contains an M-x command?*

Here is the part of my *.emacs* that works:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

(define-key evil-ex-map "b" 'helm-buffers-list)
(define-key evil-ex-map "e" 'find-file)
```

Here is the part that errors on init and I would like to get working:

```
; M-x dired
(define-key evil-ex-map "ex" 'list-directory)

; M-x list-buffers
(define-key evil-ex-map "bl" 'list-buffers)
```

Any way I can refer to those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've bound `e` to a command in the `evil-ex-map` keymap, and then you've attempted to bind the sequence `ex` to a command. You can't do that, because typing `e` would invoke the first command before you had a chance to type the `x`. Emacs sees this problem and complains about it:

```
(error "Key sequence e x starts with non-prefix key e")
```

Which would have been a super-useful thing to have copied and pasted into your question. Please *always* copy and paste the actual error message.

Comment: I will go ahead and play around with evil then!

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose another key sequence. For example, you might try this:

```
; M-x dired
(define-key evil-ex-map "x" 'list-directory)

; M-x list-buffers
(define-key evil-ex-map "l" 'list-buffers)
```

Now, in "evil-mode", if you type the letter "x", this will call `list-directory` and if you type the letter "l", this will call the function `list-buffers`.

I don't know the "evil-mode". So, before choosing one letter (like "x" or "l"), you should check whether this letter is already bound to some useful function by typing `C-h k x` or `C-h k l`.

You can get the list of all bindings by typing `C-h b` in a buffer which is using the `evil-mode`.